# How can I make this simple bank system keep an updated balance?

Tags: ruby, console

```
def account()
    puts "ENTER ACCOUNT NUMBER"
    accountnumber = gets.chomp
    puts "SUCCESS"
    modeselect()
end

def modeselect()
    puts "WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO?"
    mode = gets.chomp
    mode.upcase!
    case mode
        when "DEPOSIT"
        deposit()
        else
        account()
    end
end

def deposit()
    balance = 0
    puts "ENTER DEPOSIT AMOUNT"
    depositamount = gets.chomp.to_i
    balance == balance + depositamount
    puts "DEPOSIT SUCCESSFUL, BALANCE = #{balance}"
    modeselect()
end


account()
```

Currently, the code completes the deposit however when the deposit method is run again the balance is reset, I'm trying to make it follow across from the last time it was run, so the balance is permanently updated after each deposit.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Use instance variable, `@balance`.

Comment: what does `balance == balance + depositamount` do in your code?

Comment: I think you need to do some more reading of fundamentals. This is the perfect case for a class, but it's not clear to me that you know how to use one.

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons why the balance seems as though it is being reset.

The first is that the balance is being stored in a variable whose scope is contained within the the deposit functions block. This means that whatever value that variable has when the function finishes will not be retained. In fact the variable is no longer accessible. You can use an instance variable as suggested by Sergio using `@balance`

Secondly. The balance is being explicitly set to 0 immediately after the deposit function block is entered. An option to fix this is to only assign `@balance` a value of 0 if it has not already been assigned a value. You can do this using `@balance ||= 0`

Thirdly. The operator on the fourth line of the deposit function block `==` is a comparison operator not an assignment operator. I believe what you intend is to use `=`.

```
def account()
    puts "ENTER ACCOUNT NUMBER"
    accountnumber = gets.chomp
    puts "SUCCESS"
    modeselect()
end

def modeselect()
    puts "WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO?"
    mode = gets.chomp
    mode.upcase!
    case mode
        when "DEPOSIT"
        deposit()
        else
        account()
    end
end

def deposit()
    @balance ||= 0
    puts "ENTER DEPOSIT AMOUNT"
    depositamount = gets.chomp.to_i
    @balance = @balance + depositamount
    puts "DEPOSIT SUCCESSFUL, BALANCE = #{@balance}"
    modeselect()
end

account()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use instance variable such as `@balance`, you may need to pass the variable `balance` when calling your methods/functions to "retain" value.  Something like this (note that this code works but has severe flaws)

```
def account()
    balance ||= 0
    puts "ENTER ACCOUNT NUMBER"
    accountnumber = gets.chomp
    puts "SUCCESS"
    modeselect(balance)
end

def modeselect(balance)
    puts "WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO?"
    mode = gets.chomp
    mode.upcase!
    case mode
        when "DEPOSIT"
        #balance ||= 0
        deposit(balance)
        else
        account()
    end
end

def deposit(balance)        
    puts "ENTER DEPOSIT AMOUNT"
    depositamount = gets.chomp.to_i
    balance = balance + depositamount
    puts "DEPOSIT SUCCESSFUL, BALANCE = #{balance}"
    modeselect(balance)
end


account()
```